# Is it possible to run 2 additional monitors from a 27" iMac?

Tags: mac, external-display, displayport

Is it possible to run 2 additional monitors from a 27" iMac?

Answer (score 1):

An iMac unfortunately have only one monitor port.

But Kensington has made a pretty cool USB to DVI adapter. Enabling multi-monitor support to iMacs.

http://us.kensington.com/html/14499.html

But the performance is a bit limited... Perfect to browse the web or do office work, but don't count on it to display Full HD Content or play games.